# How could i find the store size of a repository in GraphDB?

Tags: repository, sparql, graphdb

I'm trying to calculate the total memory a repository in GraphDB takes.

Answer (score 0):

The total memory of the repository depends of the number of statements and the inference. As a starting point you can take a look at http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/9.4/free/requirements.html

If you have inference sum the implicit and explixit statements.